# Why is it not possible to add a simple rectangle in the force layout in D3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, shapes, rectangles, force-layout

i tried to add a simple rectangle into a force-layout into this code:
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045

The rectangle looks like this:

```
>  var rectangle = svg.append("rect")
>       .attr("x", 150)
>       .attr("y", 50)
>       .attr("width", 50)
>       .attr("height", 140);
```

I wonder why i does not appear? I Also used this same rectangle on a normal svg without the force-layout and there it worked very good.

Are there some specifications needed when using rectangles in the force-layout? Using other shapes, for example circles are no problem. Only the rectangles won't work.

Comment: Do you intend to use the rectangle as a 'node' 'in the force-layout, or are you adding a rectangle to the same svg that the force-layout inhabits?

Comment: I just want to add a rectangle on the same svg as the force-layout inhabits and not as a "node" of the force-layout. Using normal circles o the same svg is no problem, but using rectangles is not possible.

Comment: It should work. Make sure to define `stroke attribute`or a css class.

Comment: @Marcelo: It worked witht he help of the stroke. But this one confuse me a lot. Let me explain this: When i use this rectangle without the `stroke attribute` in a normal svg (no force-layout) then a black rectangle appears. When i do the same thing without the `stroke attribute` in the force-layout, nothing happens. But when i add the `stroke attribute` now in the force-layout, a white rectangle with a stroke appears. What is the reason for this?

Comment: @DerickKolln: The force-layout is just adding elements to `<svg>` and it should not affect the default value of the `stroke` attribute. The value of the attribute is probably being affected by some CSS defined on the page you are testing.

Comment: You don't need to set the `stroke` or any other attribute/style. The code works **as it is**, check here: http://blockbuilder.org/anonymous/1cf0d52f0e5863562b1c8b8ea60bd3d3